# Let's make a reference implementation of N-dimensional pixel binning/bucketing for python's numpy

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

I frequently want to [pixel bin/pixel bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) a numpy array, meaning, replace groups of `N` consecutive pixels with a single pixel which is the sum of the `N` replaced pixels. For example, start with the values:

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9])
```

with a bucket size of 2, this transforms into:

```
bucket(x, bucket_size=2) 
= [1+3, 7+3, 2+9]
= [4, 10, 11]
```

As far as I know, there's no numpy function that specifically does this (please correct me if I'm wrong!), so I frequently roll my own. For 1d numpy arrays, this isn't bad:

```
import numpy as np

def bucket(x, bucket_size):
    return x.reshape(x.size // bucket_size, bucket_size).sum(axis=1)

bucket_me = np.array([3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3])
print(bucket(bucket_me, bucket_size=2)) #[ 7 10  4  5]
```

...however, I get confused easily for the multidimensional case, and I end up rolling my own buggy, half-assed solution to this "easy" problem over and over again. I'd love it if we could establish a nice N-dimensional reference implementation.

- Preferably the function call would allow different bin sizes along different axes (perhaps something like `bucket(x, bucket_size=(2, 2, 3))`)
- Preferably the solution would be reasonably efficient (reshape and sum are fairly quick in numpy)
- Bonus points for handling edge effects when the array doesn't divide nicely into an integer number of buckets.
- Bonus points for allowing the user to choose the initial bin edge offset.

As suggested by Divakar, here's my desired behavior in a sample 2-D case:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [2, 3, 7, 9],
              [8, 9, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 3, 4]])

bucket(x, bucket_size=(2, 2))
= [[1 + 2 + 2 + 3, 3 + 4 + 7 + 9],
   [8 + 9 + 0 + 0, 1 + 0 + 3 + 4]]
= [[8, 23],
   [17, 8]]
```

...hopefully I did my arithmetic correctly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively from as_strided :

```
x = array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [2, 3, 7, 9],
           [8, 9, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 3, 4]])

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided     
def bucket(x,bucket_size):
      x=np.ascontiguousarray(x)
      oldshape=array(x.shape)
      newshape=concatenate((oldshape//bucket_size,bucket_size))
      oldstrides=array(x.strides)
      newstrides=concatenate((oldstrides*bucket_size,oldstrides))
      axis=tuple(range(x.ndim,2*x.ndim))
      return as_strided (x,newshape,newstrides).sum(axis)
```

if a dimension not divide evenly into the corresponding dimension of x, remaining elements are lost.

verification :

```
In [9]: bucket(x,(2,2))
Out[9]: 
array([[ 8, 23],
       [17,  8]])
```

Comment: If a dimension of the bucket does not divide into the corresponding dimension of the array, an error is raised and the function doesn't execute at all - it isn't the case that remaining elements are lost. (Also, this answer is identical to the method I suggested 35 minutes earlier :-))

Comment: No error are raised in my test.  I write it as a complement of view_as_blocks, which force exact division. Sorry for the delay, I had to think ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do most of the fiddly work with skimage's [`view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks). This function is [implemented using `as_strided`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#l10) so it is very efficient (it just changes the stride information to reshape the array). Because it's written in Python/NumPy, you can always copy the code if you don't have skimage installed.

After applying that function, you just need to sum the N trailing axes of the reshaped array (where N is the length of the `bucket_size` tuple). Here's a new `bucket()` function:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

def bucket(x, bucket_size):
    blocks = view_as_blocks(x, bucket_size)
    tup = tuple(range(-len(bucket_size), 0))
    return blocks.sum(axis=tup)
```

Then for example:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 3, 7, 3, 2, 9])
>>> bucket(x, bucket_size=(2,))
array([ 4, 10, 11])

>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [2, 3, 7, 9],
                  [8, 9, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 3, 4]])

>>> bucket(x, bucket_size=(2, 2))
array([[ 8, 23],
       [17,  8]])

>>> y = np.arange(6*6*6).reshape(6,6,6)
>>> bucket(y, bucket_size=(2, 2, 3))
array([[[ 264,  300],
        [ 408,  444],
        [ 552,  588]],

       [[1128, 1164],
        [1272, 1308],
        [1416, 1452]],

       [[1992, 2028],
        [2136, 2172],
        [2280, 2316]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify different bin sizes along each axis for `ndarray` cases, you can use iteratively use [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) along each axis of it, like so  -

```
def bucket(x, bin_size):
    ndims = x.ndim
    out = x.copy()
    for i in range(ndims):
        idx = np.append(0,np.cumsum(bin_size[i][:-1]))
        out = np.add.reduceat(out,idx,axis=i)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [126]: x
Out[126]: 
array([[165, 107, 133,  82, 199],
       [ 35, 138,  91, 100, 207],
       [ 75,  99,  40, 240, 208],
       [166, 171,  78,   7, 141]])

In [127]: bucket(x, bin_size = [[2, 2],[3, 2]])
Out[127]: 
array([[669, 588],
       [629, 596]])

#  [2, 2] are the bin sizes along axis=0
#  [3, 2] are the bin sizes along axis=1

# array([[165, 107, 133, | 82, 199],
#        [ 35, 138,  91, | 100, 207],
# -------------------------------------
#        [ 75,  99, 40,  | 240, 208],
#        [166, 171, 78,  | 7, 141]])

In [128]: x[:2,:3].sum()
Out[128]: 669

In [129]: x[:2,3:].sum()
Out[129]: 588

In [130]: x[2:,:3].sum()
Out[130]: 629

In [131]: x[2:,3:].sum()
Out[131]: 596
```