# How to evaluate the sum of values within array blocks

Tags: python, numpy

I have data array, with shape 100x100. I want to divide it into 5x5 blocks, and each block has 20x20 grids. The value of each block I want is the sum of all values in it.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish it?

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X)*np.sin(Y)
Z_new = np.zeros((5, 5))
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    Z_new[i, j] = np.sum(Z[i*20:20+i*20, j*20:20+j*20])
```

This is based on index, how if based on x?

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X)*np.sin(Y)
x_new = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
y_new = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
```

Z_new?

Comment: For solutions in any number of dimensions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269508/lets-make-a-reference-implementation-of-n-dimensional-pixel-binning-bucketing-f/36269734#36269734

Comment: @ajcr I am reopening this because the duplicate linked question would involve considerable overhead of setting up for a generic ndarray case, which isn't needed to solve a case like this. Hope this sounds okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blockwise operations in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325176/blockwise-operations-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) splitting each of those two axes into two each with shape `(5,20)` to form a `4D` array and then sum reduce along the axes having the lengths `20`, like so -

```
Z_new = Z.reshape(5,20,5,20).sum(axis=(1,3))
```

Functionally the same, but potentially faster option with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
Z_new = np.einsum('ijkl->ik',Z.reshape(5,20,5,20))
```

**Generic block size**

Extending to a generic case -

```
H,W = 5,5 # block-size
m,n = Z.shape
Z_new = Z.reshape(H,m//H,W,n//W).sum(axis=(1,3))
```

With `einsum` that becomes -

```
Z_new = np.einsum('ijkl->ik',Z.reshape(H,m//H,W,n//W))
```

To compute average/mean across blocks, use `mean` instead of `sum` method.

**Generic block size and reduction operation**

Extending to use `reduction` operations that have [`ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce) supporting multiple `axes` parameter with `axis` for reductions, it would be -

```
def blockwise_reduction(a, height, width, reduction_func=np.sum):
    m,n = a.shape
    a4D = a.reshape(height,m//height,width,n//width)
    return reduction_func(a4D,axis=(1,3))
```

Thus, to solve our specific case, it would be :

```
blockwise_reduction(Z, height=5, width=5)
```

and for a block-wise average computation, it would be -

```
blockwise_reduction(Z, height=5, width=5, reduction_func=np.mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following.

```
t = np.eye(5).repeat(20, axis=1)
Z_new = t.dot(Z).dot(t.T)
```

This is correct because `Z_new[i, j] = t[i, k] * Z[k, l] * t[j, l]`

Also this seems faster than Divakar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem is a very good candidate for a function like [scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum.html) since it allows "grouping" and "labelling" terms. You will have what you want with something like:

```
labels = [[20*(y//5) + x//5 for x in range(100)] for y in range(100)]
s = scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum(Z, labels, range(400))
```

(Not tested, but that is the idea).