# numpy: efficient summation of values within variably-sized array blocks

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, scientific-computing

The problem is very similar to that in [How to evaluate the sum of values within array blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383107/how-to-evaluate-the-sum-of-values-within-array-blocks), where I need to sum up elements in a matrix by blocks. What is different here is that the blocks could have different sizes. For example, given a 4-by-5 matrix

```
1 1 | 1 1 1
----|------
1 1 | 1 1 1
1 1 | 1 1 1
1 1 | 1 1 1
```

and block sizes `1 3` along the rows and `2 3` along the columns, the result should be a 2-by-2 matrix:

```
2 3
6 9
```

Is there a way of doing this without loops?

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a good fit to use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to basically sum along rows and then along cols -

```
def sum_blocks(a, row_sizes, col_sizes):
    # Sum rows based on row-sizes
    s1 = np.add.reduceat(a,np.r_[0,row_sizes[:-1].cumsum()],axis=0)

    # Sum cols from row-summed output based on col-sizes
    return np.add.reduceat(s1,np.r_[0,col_sizes[:-1].cumsum()],axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5))

In [46]: a
Out[46]: 
array([[5, 0, 3, 3, 7],
       [3, 5, 2, 4, 7],
       [6, 8, 8, 1, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 1, 5]])

In [47]: row_sizes = np.array([1,3])
    ...: col_sizes = np.array([2,3])

In [48]: sum_blocks(a, row_sizes, col_sizes)
Out[48]: 
array([[ 5, 13],
       [36, 42]])
```