# the elegant/efficient way for performing grid mask type of operation on numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix,e.g., 100*100,  and would like to compute some statistics for every 2*2 grid. Naturally, I can use loop to perform it. Are there more elegant/efficient operation to perform this kind of operation?

Comment: See if this helps out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383107.

Comment: With or without overlap in the subarrays? There are a few resources on the subject available online. [`skimage.util.view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks) and [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows) are solid options.